# Why result is different if prefix variable is passed in SQUARE macro?

Tags: c++

Could you please explain why the below program's result is different?

Program :

```
#define MUL(X) X*X
int main()
{
  int i=3;
  cout<<MUL(++i)<<"\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
25
```

Comment: Think about it. If `X` is `++i`, what is `X*X`?

Comment: Different than what?

Comment: @user2079303 Good question, but from the wording of the title, I'd guess the OP means "different from NOT passing the prefix to the macro", or, performing the `++` before calling the macro. `++i; MUL(i)`

Comment: Because it's [undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points), a classic example BTW. It's expanded to `++i * ++i`, similar case to the `i++ * ++i` explained in the first answer

Comment: Different as in could be different on different platforms/compilers/days of the week because of undefined behaviour.  Also, If you must use a macro like this, use `#define MUL(X) ((X)*(X))` (i.e. wrap uses of `X` and the whole thing in parentheses) so that "normal" uses will work (e.g. your `MUL(3+1)` gives `7` [3 + (1*3) + 1] instead of `16` [(3+1)*(3+1)]).

Comment: Sorry.. How the result is 25 there? I thought like (++i * ++i) means (4 * 5)=20. But here the result is different from what i expected.

Comment: Nothing **can** be expected because it's undefined.  It could (and seems to for you) do both increments _before_ the multiplication (5*5), it could do (4*5), (5*4) or, possibly, (4*4).

Comment: Oh! ok, it is undefined behaviour? But could you please explain why? And what are the other cases in macros which are undefined?

Comment: @TejaswiBurgula: There are two issues here.  First is that C doesn't force left-to-right evaluation of arithmetic expressions.  Second is that the side effect of the `++` operator doesn't have to be applied immediately upon evaluation.  This means that the result of an expression like `i++ * i++` will vary based on platform, compiler settings, even surrounding code.  The language standard calls this out as *undefined behavior* so that compilers aren't required to handle the issue in any particular way; as far as the standard is concerned, *any* result is "correct".

Comment: Right. And if you're still interested in why this particular compiler, under these particular circumstances, gives this result, it's possibly something like: the variable is stored in a register rather than a memory location. The left hand part is calculated (and stored in the register), the right hand part is calculated (and stored in the register), the multiplication is done (again, on the register). But your mileage may vary. it _will_ vary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to analyse this, let's expand the macro, which becomes `++i * ++i`.

Formally, the behaviour of `++i * ++i` is *undefined* as `*` is not a sequencing point, and `++` mutates the `i`. So the compiler can do anything, and no further explanation is necessary.

If your compiler supports `typeof` (which is compile-time evaluable so will not do any incrementing), and *expression statements*, then the safe version of your macro is

```
#define MUL(i) ({    \
    typeof(i) j = (i);  \
    j*j;                \
})
```

although it would be wise to avoid a macro altogether and use a function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's in fact UB, not just indeterminate. The two `++` have side effects on the scalar `i` in unsequenced manner which is explicitly UB according to [intro.execution]/15.

Comment: I'm wrestling with this too, over lunch.

Comment: Yeah, it's UB, you shouldn't pay attention to me before I've had coffee (or after, perhaps).

Comment: BTW, why do you assume C++03? By now, I'm assuming C++>=11 unless specified otherwise. Do you think that's not the more common option on here?

Comment: @BoBTFish: pick a random C++ project chosen uniformly from all the still-maintained projects by any corporation in the world, the chance that it's C++>=11 is probably still less than 10% (probably considerably less).

Comment: `j` can be const, and there's no point in parenthesising the right-hand side of an assignment. I know it's habit, but still. :)

Comment: Note that a) rather than `typeof(i)`, one can just write `auto` (or even better `const auto`); b) `({...})` to create an expression block is a GCC extension, not valid in standard C++.  (I still occasionally miss my beloved VALOF from BCPL in 1980)